# Segmentation fault when calling method on base class pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I'm trying to construct a FSM for a simple compiler.
I've chosen to create a fixed-size array with interface pointers to the states. This concept proved to be successful with a simple placeholder FSM that reads HTML.
However, the real FSM won't work: I get a segmentation fault (at 0x0) when calling a states processing method.

Here's the instancing:

```
this->states[0] = new State0();
this->states[1] = new State1();
this->states[2] = new State2();
this->states[3] = new State3();
this->states[4] = new State4();
[...]
```

When I step through it, I can see the corresponding address changing after each assignment.

The array is defined this way:

```
#define STATE_COUNT 17
[...]
IState * states[STATE_COUNT];
```

IState:

```
class IState {
public:
    virtual ~IState() {};
    virtual int getNextState(char) = 0;
    virtual bool isFinal() = 0;
    virtual TokenType getTokenType() = 0;
};
```

State0, with code minimized for testing purposes:

```
class State0 : public IState
{
public:
    virtual ~State0();
    int getNextState(char c)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    bool isFinal()
    {
        return this->final;
    }

    TokenType getTokenType()
    {
        return this->tokenType;
    }
private:
    TokenType tokenType;
    bool final;
};
```

Now, the following line of code causes the SEGFAULT:

```
this->nextState = this->states[currentState]->getNextState(c);
```

`currentState` is 0, since it happends on the very first call.

So, I think it's neither a scope problem nor a NULL pointer. Except perhaps a NULL this pointer in the state objects?

Comment: Are you really sure `currentState` is `0`? Did you print it before the call?

Comment: I stepped through, so yes. But I've identified the problem in the meantime - I forgot to switch the included header when I switched the object files. D:

Comment: Unfortunately a very common error, even among experienced programmers I can assure you!

Comment: Daniel, welcome to Stack Overflow. If the question may be of value to others please post an answer in the answer section. Posting an answer in the question body is horrible practice, it will get you downvoted. If this is of no value to anyone, delete it. But be careful ... too much deleting and you will get banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this problem was due to my own carelessness. I edited my Makefile to build other objects but failed to change the headers to the new ones in my code. So I linked ("externally" similar) new object files to other code still using the old headers.